# How to turn a shapefile into a table?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, table, dbf

How do you completely turn a shapefile (created with QGIS, including .shx and the other 4-5 files) into one tabular dataset.

I am actually doing this when I import the shapefile into Postgresql database, but I was wondering if there is the opportunity to do that in another way.

Comment: What do you mean 'turn into'? The dbf is just the attributes. It (and an Excel file which isn't even a database) are not capable of storing some of the information contained in those other files in a meaningful way. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @ChrisW I mean I want to see all the information of a layer, including id,columns I may have added and geometry information in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is create a CSV for the output, which in QGIS there are options on how to export the geometry.

Right-click the layer

Choose Save As

Choose Format - CSV

now notice the Layer Options settings > GEOMETRY

do you want your geometry stored as WKT, XY's, etc.?

In my example, I turned zip code polygon shapefiles into CSV using WKT.

Here's what the CSV looks like in LibreOffice Calc:

[image]

And here's the CSV in QGIS displaying the geometry in WKT:

[image]

Then you can simply save the CSV to an excel file or DBF from there...

Comment: when I do this it will turn the shapefile into a dbf, but I can't get the geometry features I have added in a column into the same table. I am mainly interested into the column that describes the geometry.

Comment: @drizo gotcha - updating answer shortly...

Comment: OH GOD THAT IS SO GOOD! I WAS SEARCHING FOR THIS FOR AGES! YOU SAVED MY ... YOU SAVED ME!

Comment: @drizo right on!!! Good luck!!!

Comment: Thank you, but why in same layers I can't see the 'geometry' in layer settings?

Comment: ah ok my bad I found it